# NoMethodError when calling a helper method in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine-plugins

I'm working on a simple timesheet plugin for Redmine, all was going well until I tried to use helpers.

The helper:

```
module TimesheetHelper
def first_day_in_week(datum)
  return unless datum.kind_of? Date
  datum - datum.wday
end
def last_day_in_week(datum)
  return unless datum.kind_of? Date
  datum + (6 - datum.wday)
end
end
```

In the view I have
    helper "timesheet"

But I've also tried

```
helper :timesheet
```

and

```
helper TimesheetHelper
```

In the first line of index.rhtml it says

```
<h2><%= l :timesheet_for %> <% first_day_of_week @week %> <%=l :and %>  
<% last_day_of_week @week %></h2>
```

and rails throws a NoMethodError on `first_day_of_week @week`

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is

```
def first_day_in_week(datum)
```

not

```
def first_day_of_week(datum)
```

The name is not the same, so the method is not found ^^

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my enormous fail. +1 for the patience